# Printing times tables: How do I add a new line between results?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Simple one here I am sure but I am still learning and I am not too sure on how I can add lines in between the lines of the timetable.

This is my code:

```
def table_all():
    for line in range(1,13):
        for table in range(1,13):
            print(line * table, end=" ")
    print
```

here is the result:
[image: Outout]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image: Intended output]

If anybody has a more efficient way of doing this then please share. Don't hate me for asking a simple question, everybody has to start learning somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Print a `new line` at the end of every iteration of outer loop.

```
def table_all():
    for line in range(1,13):
        for table in range(1,13):
            print(line * table, end=" ")
        print("\n")
```

Comment: This did it, thanks! I think I actually did try doing this before but I used '\n' not "\n". Didn't think it would make a difference, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

This will return a string thats contain a new line each linefor:

```
def table_all():
    string = ""
    for line in range(1,13):
        for table in range(1,13):
            string += str(line * table) + " "
        string += "\n"
    return string

print(table_all())
```